# Having issue to upload 10,000 file into IPFS directly

Tags: ipfs

I'm trying to upload a lot of JSON files (10,000 JSON file) in IPFS using the following API from [py-ipfs-http-client package](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/py-ipfs-http-client), and [go-ipfs v0.7](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs) and when I try to open the hash with localhost IPFS domain it works `http://localhost:8081/ipfs/<hash>` but not with the main ipfs link `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<hash>`, just keep loading forever.

I tried again the same process the next day, but just a random small selection of the hashes started to work in `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<hash>`, but the other do the same.

Then I tried to use [Pinata](https://github.com/PinataCloud/Pinata-SDK) website to upload these JSON files but it kept loading without any successful message, and when I did a refresh it didn't work.

I need your help to understand this behavior. And what may I do other than that to solve this challenge?
Thanks.